# error code when creating a virtual view in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, create-view

I'm new to Oracle SQL, and for the life of me i cant figure out why I continue getting error "missing right parenthesis" on my code. I've looked for missing or extra commas and parenthesis but cant figure it out. Help please! My query is below:

```
CREATE VIEW PRODUCT_SUMMARY_V 
AS SELECT 
PROD_ID, 
EXTRACT (CALENDAR_YEAR FROM TIME_ID) "YEAR", 
EXTRACT (CALENDAR_MONTH_NAME FROM TIME_ID) "MONTH",  
SUM(AMOUNT_SOLD) "TOTAL_AMOUNT_SOLD", 
SUM(QUANTITY_SOLD) "TOTAL_QUANTITY_SOLD",
ROUND(SUM(AMOUNT_SOLD)/SUM(QUANTITY_SOLD),2) "AVG_SALE_PRICE"
FROM MY_SALES
GROUP BY PROD_ID, CALENDAR_YEAR, CALENDAR_MONTH_NAME
ORDER BY PROD_ID;
```

Answer (score 3):

You are extracting wrong value from the `TIME_ID` with the help of `EXTRACT()` function.

```
  SQL> CREATE VIEW PRODUCT_SUMMARY_V 
  AS SELECT 
  PROD_ID, 
  EXTRACT (YEAR FROM TIME_ID) "YEAR", 
  EXTRACT (MONTH FROM TIME_ID) "MONTH",  
  SUM(AMOUNT_SOLD) "TOTAL_AMOUNT_SOLD", 
  SUM(QUANTITY_SOLD) "TOTAL_QUANTITY_SOLD",
  ROUND(SUM(AMOUNT_SOLD)/ SUM(QUANTITY_SOLD),2) "AVG_SALE_PRICE"
  FROM MY_SALES
  GROUP BY PROD_ID, EXTRACT (YEAR FROM TIME_ID), EXTRACT (MONTH FROM TIME_ID)
  ORDER BY PROD_ID;  

 View created.
```

However the error message is misleading because the parameter of the `EXTRACT` function is incorrect and it treats it as the column of a table.The syntax checker treats the statement as `SELECT EXTRACT(CALENDAR_YEAR FROM TIME_ID`.

```
SQL> SELECT EXTRACT(CALENDAR_YEAR FROM TIME_ID;
SELECT EXTRACT(CALENDAR_YEAR FROM TIME_ID
                             *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

For details:[Extract](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions050.htm)